# Trying to extract "suburb name" from "12 street name, suburb name, CTG 1234" in php using regexp

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract `suburb name` from the following:

```
12 street name, suburb name, CTG 1234
```

in PHP using regexp.

- Both street and suburb name can be any number of word long.
- CTG is acronym for state and is always known and always same.
- It is followed by 4 digit postcode.

I have come up with the following regexp but cant quite catch what I want.

```
/[\.|,]+\s*(.*?)[\.|,]+*\s*CTG\d{4,4}$/i
```

where:

- `CTG\d{4,4}$` is to find the postcode and state from the left.
- `[\.|,]*\s*` is to match at at least one dot or coma followed by zero or many white space after street and suburb name.
- `(.*?)` is to capture my target. suburb name.
- `*?` so it will be non greedy.

Above used in preg_match() with any given subject returning a array of match, where:

- `arrey[0]` = whole match
- `arrey[1]=12` = street name, suburb name

However if tried in http://www.regexplanet.com it seems to work fine.

Comment: delimiter undefined. can be coma or dot.

Comment: So you can use then `preg_split` defining several delimiters.

Comment: So what is the problem, you only want `array[1]` to contain `suburb name` ?

Comment: yes. wanted arrey[1] to contain only suburb name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the suburb name with:

```
$str = '12 street name, suburb name, CTG 1234';
$pattern = '/[^.,]++(?=[.,]\s*CTG \d{4}$)/';

preg_match($pattern, $str, $result);

echo $result[0];
```

To only match the suburb name, I use a lookahead assertion `(?=...)` that performs only a check without recording the match.

Pattern details:

```
/
[^.,]++            # all that is not a . or a , one or more times (possessive)
(?=                # open lookahead assertion (means "followed by")
    [.,]\s*        # a . or a , with optional white characters
    CTG \d{4}$     # CTG, a space, four digits, end of string
)                  # close the lookahead
/
```

Comment: Thanks. yor regexp is working! even better that only shows arrey[0]=suburb name. http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1r6

Comment: how did you get arrey[0] contain the suburb name and not the whole match? please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one `^(.*)[\.,]\s+(.*)[\.,]\s+CTG\s+(\d+)$` extracting matching group no. **2**.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you missed the space between CTG and the digits (also periods don't need to be escaped inside brackets, nor do you need the OR pipe). This should work for your needs:

```
/.*[.,]+\s*(.*)[.,]+\s*CTG\s*\d{4,4}$/i
```

You can see the above pattern with your example text on [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1r2)